# J2EE - How to remove empty space,blank lines from server response

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

Is there a way to remove blank lines from server response? I have tried out:

```
<init-param>
          <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

and

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
```

which didn't solve the issue properly since in init param method it removed even space between words, 2nd method didn't work either since it needs java servlet version to be 2.5.

Your advice will be very helpful ..

Answer (score 1):

you should create a filter-servlet that remove blank lines and chained the response to your servlet.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Thought of this way but there is a performance overhead on this if am rite. Are there other ways to solve this ?

Comment: This is the simpliest way to do it with your servlet version.No performance overhead with chaining 2 servlets in your case.

Answer (score 1):

when the server convert the JSP page to servlet it add implicitly blank lines (\n).
add out.clear() befor writing data to clear out object.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following directives to your page and the lines should disappear:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml" %>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use an IDE like eclipse. Where you can just select the whole code and format it and follow all java syntax guidelines by just right clicking and seletcing a few options.
Please use good IDE's all of them will help you follow good guidelines and make your work simpler and easier to read and understand